# Terraform: Build resource in one environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I want to build an s3 bucket only when we are using our prod account. We are using terraform 11.7 which I don't think supports the 'null' choice for if statement

Does anyone know if something like this can be done in terraform 11:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "feedback_service_bucket" {
  bucket = "${var.account_name == "prod" ? "ces-${var.environment}-QA-compendex" : null}" 
  acl = "private"

}
```

I will upgrade soon to terraform 13, but as this is required in this sprint I don't have time. We have a prod.tfvars file which is used when the applied environment is set to prod (obviously), so if the above is not possible, is there a way to put an entire resource into a tfvars file. I know you can use variables, but I'm not sure about resource. Any help would be great, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know if something like this can be done in terraform 11:

You can use `count` for such scenario:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "feedback_service_bucket" {
  count = "${var.account_name == "prod" ? 1 : 0}"
  bucket = "ces-${var.environment}-QA-compendex" 
  acl = "private"
}
```

You can refer to this: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html#conditionals

> I will upgrade soon to terraform 13, but as this is required in this sprint I don't have time.

For info, Terraform 0.13 won't give you much advantages for this specific use case. You would still use `count`. What changes in 0.13 regarding conditional resources is that you have an alternative using `for_each` - introduced with v0.12 - and in which you can achieve the same behavior.